# No puedo mostrar datos en un select problemas con un foreach al mostrar datos en un select

Tags: laravel

```
$anos =\DB::table('organizador_tareas')
            ->join('años_trabajo', 'años_trabajo.id', '=', 'organizador_tareas.ano')
            ->select('años_trabajo.anos_trabajo')
            ->get();

//         dd($anos);


        return \View::make('empleado_inicio',compact('paises','nivel_academico'
            ,'titulo_obtenido','departamento_honduras','tipo_contratacion','dep_icf','bancos'))->with(
            [
                'anos' => $anos,
                'contador' => 0
            ]
        );
    }





@foreach($anos as $anos)
                         <div class="form-group">
                             {!! Form::label('año', 'Año:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                             <div class="col-lg-10">
                                 {{Form::select('año',$anos,['required'=>'required'])}}
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         @endforeach
```

Comment: ¿En qué línea aparece dicho error?

Comment: no me sale en ninguna linea solo ala hora de ejecutar la vista me tira este error  htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\resources\views\modales\modal-registro-empleados_pestañas.blade.php) (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\resources\views\modales\modal-registro-empleados_pestañas.blade.php)

Comment: Lo mas probable es queso se debe a la letra `ñ`, como recomendación, trata de codificar ver eso y otra cosa, trata de no poner letras con caracteres especiales en los nombres de archivos en laravel , como por ejemplo tu archivo blade `empleados_pestañas.blade.php`, porque podría ser por esto también el error. Saludos.

Comment: Normalmente Laravel con Whoops muestran la línea donde ocurre, revisa el pantallazo del error.

Comment: return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', $doubleEncode);linea 564

Comment: ese es el error y la linea que marca 564

Comment: Deberías evitar campos para sus tablas o campos con letras tildadas o letras como la ñ , a menudo traen problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que algún caracter especial se haya colado en los valores que intentas mostrar en el `select`. Añádele también los signos de interrogación a las llaves de blade, como hiciste para la etiqueta `label`, te quedaría así:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
   {!! Form::select('año',$anos,['required'=>'required']) !!}
</div>
```

Un saludo